# error in injecting quartz dependency in my pom.xml

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler, spring-batch, pom.xml

I'm  working with spring batch and I want to add quartz scheduler to  automate the repetition of a job  at specific intervals ..I've injected  its dependencies but my `pom.xml` generated an error !

I'm confused. Any help is apreciated.

edit:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>

            <configuration>
                <port>8585</port>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
  </dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
<version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
<version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
<version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

this is the error displayed when I add quartz dependency :

[image]

Comment: please add your pom file to understand more..

Comment: please see my update ..

Comment: `<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
 <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
` This artifact having the taglib:jar,might be possible that it is not able to download the jar. So please check the jar is downloaded properly or not  and open through winzip and check the path.

Comment: the mentionned  jar is downloaded correctly ..but quartz jar isn't .. I don't know what to do ..I'm blocked !